# TS ignore inside render method of .tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This error drives me crazy

```
Error:(57, 32) TS2339: Property 'mongoProjects' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticCont...'.
```

As I understand it, it's impossible to fix. Typescript in React is a real hassle!

Is it possible to add a ts ignore comment inside the tsx render method?

[image]

```
<GraphQlDataFetcher query={getProjects()}>
            {(data, refetch) => (
              <>
                <CreateProject mongoProjects={data.projects}/> // ts ignore on this error
                <BootstrapTable
                  keyField="_id"
                  data={data.projects}
                  columns={columns}
                />
              </>
            )}
          </GraphQlDataFetcher>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this my friend

```
<GraphQlDataFetcher query={getProjects()}>
        {(data, refetch) => (
          <>
            {
              // @ts-ignore
              <CreateProject mongoProjects={data.projects}/>                      
            }
            <BootstrapTable
              keyField="_id"
              data={data.projects}
              columns={columns}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </GraphQlDataFetcher>
```

Comment: MY HERO!  You rule . . .